# CPU Architecture at run-time

Tags: macos, architecture, process

Is there a way to find the process architecture on runtime on MAC?

I am using `sizeof(int) == 4` for 32-bit and `sizeof(int) == 8` for 64 bit. Is there an elegant way?

Comment: I'm wondering if it matters. Are you sending the data anywhere?

Comment: If only targeting, say, OS X, I'm sure that has some functionality that is query-able without relying on the `sizeof` operator (the `sizeof` is a *compile time* constant, is it not? -- in which case there are better-suited CPP defines I suspect)

Comment: I assume you are using multiple architecture binaries?

Comment: @Yann, yeah, I need to load the library based on the architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`@property(readonly) NSInteger executableArchitecture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008799-CH1-SW8) and the Constants [`Mach-O Architecture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Mach_O_Architecture) of `NSBundle`

```
NSInteger architecture = [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] executableArchitecture];
if(architecture == NSBundleExecutableArchitectureX86_64) {
    NSLog(@"running on 64bits");
else if (architecture == NSBundleExecutableArchitectureI386) {
    NSLog(@"running on 32bits");
} else {
    NSLog(@"running somewhere else");
}
```